# Error Installing yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:~6.0 with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:~6.0 into my project but I keep getting the following error:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:~6.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework == 5.2.39.0 is satisfiable by larave
l/framework[v5.2.39] but those are rejected by your minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.0.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove vlucas/phpdotenv v2.3.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/f
ramework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0
.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.2
3, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32,
 v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.35, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
    - Conclusion: don't install vlucas/phpdotenv v2.3.0
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires vlucas/phpdotenv ~1.0 -> satisfiable by vl
ucas/phpdotenv[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, v1.0.8, v1.0.9, v1
.1.0, v1.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.0, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.1, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.2, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.3, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.4, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.5, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[1.0.6, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[v1.0.8, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[v1.0.9, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[v1.1.0, v2.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: vlucas/phpdotenv[v1.1.1, v2.3.0].
    - Installation request for vlucas/phpdotenv == 2.3.0.0 -> satisfiable by vluca
s/phpdotenv[v2.3.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/html": "~5.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I have php 5.6.19 installed and Laravel 5.2.39. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have "laravel/framework": "5.2.*" on require and "laravel/framework": "5.0.*", on require-dev?

Comment: DOH! You're right missed that. Need more caffeine thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require and require dev were different larval versions in my composer.json. Thanks to Calin Blaga for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

just use this. 
follow the 
https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter

and your code will be

```
        Route
    Route::get('datatables',['uses'=>'DatatablesController@getIndex', 'as' => 'datatables']);
    Route::get('datatables/{data}',['uses'=>'DatatablesController@anyData', 'as' => 'datatables.data']);

    Controller
      public function anyData()
        {
           $users = User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])->get();
        return Datatables::of($users)->make();
        }

    JS
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{!! url('datatables/data') !!}'
        });
```